# will this voltage tripler circuit work?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, 555

I need power supply for my opamp as i only have 5 volt supply. I need at least 14 volt power supply so that i can power my opamp. I recently got this circuit of voltage tripler using 555 IC. Will it work ? Do i need to add some other circuit with this??

[image]

Comment: If you want to drive a decent load you should pick a boost converter

Comment: You've picked a Villiard cascade there, a Dickson cascade has lower output impedance, move C7 negative to same point as C2 negative.

Comment: It might work but something like this module: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/2PCS-MT3608-DC-DC-2A-Step-Up-Panel-Power-Supply-Boost-Module-Converter-Plate-/122466035086?hash=item1c838b658e:g:49sAAOSwIWVZASY7  will perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

A CMOS version 555 should work.  The output needs to be low impedance and rail to rail and that's exactly what you get from a CMOS output.  You could also use a CMOS hex inverter IC.

You also need to consider the voltage drop of the diodes.   Non-ideal diodes typically drops between 0.6 and 0.7 volts. Germanium and schottky diodes have a lower voltage drop, but that's not going to help here unless you can find diodes with 0.25 volt drop or less.

Adding a third stage should do the trick, even with 0.7 volt drop for each diode.  20 V - 6*0.7 V = 15.8 V (unloaded)

You should also add some reservoir capacitance on the 15 V output.  And poke around with an oscilloscope to see how the charge pump behaves under load.

And don't be surprised if it's terrible when loaded, if you need 15 V for something serious you may want to use an already existing boost converter as suggested in the comments by Ratchet Freak.